# Flutter Layout Roadblock

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am relatively new to Flutter - been working on my app for a couple of months now and have made fine progress in some areas but not others. I am having trouble figuring out the 'right way' to layout a series of screens of mine, all of which are somewhat similar in some ways.

In short, besides the app bar, the scaffold will hold a container, in which I have a Cupertino Segmented Control. The segmented control is used to switch between an IndexedStack control that is 'below' it.

Each child of the stack can have varying content - sometimes a listview, sometimes a form with many text inputs, switches, etc..  So the structure might logically look like this:

```
Body
  SegmentedControl
  IndexStack
    Child 1
    Child N
```

My problem is that I want/need all of the children of the stack to 'fill the remaining area' of the body. So, if I can just make up some numbers here for example: device is 600 px tall, appbar takes 40, segmented control takes 60, leaving 500 px for each stack child. In practice though, I cannot seem to deduce the 'remaining content height' of my Body. I am hoping (and thinking) that there is some type of layout widget or container widget that 'auto sizes to all remaining space' but as of yet have not found it. I've tried many combinations of many different widgets and none seem to do the trick.  Here is a condensed block of my layout code:

```
body: Container(
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
        child: CupertinoSegmentedControl(
          children: tabOptions,
          onValueChanged: tabChanged,
          groupValue: curTabIndex,
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        height: 400.0, //needs to be 'all the rest' instead of a constant
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(“Example Text - would really be list tiles"),
            Text(“displaying results of database query"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
     ],            
   ), 
 ),
```

I only showed one child of the indexed stack. In practice I could have several. If I do not give the Container holding the ListView a finite height (and some sort of width), the RenderBox cannot paint, i.e., I get errors. The challenge is to have the stack children take up as much horizontal and vertical space as is available, and, for their contents to be 'scrollable' in cases where that content overruns the laid out height. I'll try anything anyone suggests... I'm certain there is a way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

Replace the Container widget with an Expanded which will expand on the available space like below

```
   Expanded(
   //Container(
    //height: 400.0, //needs to be 'all the rest' instead of a constant
   // width: double.infinity,
    child: ListView(
```

Expanded docs: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Option 2:

Use MediaQuery.of(context).size.height to calculate the desired height. Not sure if this will work or even if it is a good practice.

Comment: Thank you @LenosV - using the Expanded was in fact the right way to go. My psuedo-code did not show it, but I do have an IndexedStack. Thus the final [rough] structure ended up like such:  Body contains a Column.  Within the Column are two siblings, a SizedBox (holds the SegmentedControl) and an Expanded.  Within the Expanded sits my IndexedStack, which has three Container children. The first one holds a ListView and all is happy now!  p.s. I had tried the MediaQuery thing but that cannot execute within the Build block - so couldn't get size anyway...  Thanks again!